# MVC LINQ error, "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new in MVC and in using LINQ. I'm trying to join 3 tables on my project. These are my tables.

Client table,

[image]

Event table,

[image]

Register table,

[image]

This my linq statement,

```
OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1 dbClient = new OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1();
        OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1 dbEvents = new OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1();
        OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1 dbRegEvents = new OnlineRegistrationDBEntities1();
        var displayRegisteredEvents = from x in dbRegEvents.Registers
                                      join c in dbClient.clients on x.email equals c.email
                                      join e in dbEvents.events on x.eventname equals e.eventname
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          fullname = c.fullname,
                                          eventname = e.eventname,
                                          email = c.email,
                                          guestnumber = x.guestnumber,
                                          payment_amount = x.payment_amount
                                      };

        ViewBag.viewRegisteredEvents = displayRegisteredEvents;
        return View();
```

I'm trying to show the results on a table format in my view like this,

[image]

But when I run the program I got this error, **The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts**. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: why you create 3 instances of DbContext, you must create only one, and use it to query all 3 tables.

Comment: why you use three context, one is sufficient, and use `displayRegisteredEvents.ToList()`

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you so much. But I got an error that, ''object' does not contain a definition for 'fullname"